# Tuple<Guid, string, int> does not contain a constructor that takes that many arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting the error in the subject line based on the following code:

```
var myReport = new List<Tuple<Guid, string, int>>();
myReport.Add(new Tuple<Guid, string, int>(domainId, domainName, domainCount));
```

domainId, domainName and domainCount all have the expected data types.  Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Having more then one operation per line is very bad for debugging. Try splitting it up over multiple lines using temporary variables. Do not be worried about performance - the JiT is very good at cutting out "pointless" temporary variables in release builds. Also a type alias would help keeping the need to write those types every time down to a managable level.

Comment: Have you checked with the autocompletion what parameters is your Tuple class expecting? Would it be possible that you're redefining a Tuple type somewhere in your project (or in a referenced library) ?

Comment: You can always use the `Tuple.Create` static methods so that you don't have to specify the generic type parameters. If that changes the error  message to be some sort of type mismatch, you'll have identified where some assumptions have failed.

Comment: That code is fine on its own (I've just double-checked it) so as Kevin says, it may well be a matter of having another `Tuple` type around. Could you hover over `Tuple` to see what it shows?

Answer (score 13):

The problem was with a missing semicolon on the subsequent line of code. I see this type of error every once in a while.  The compilation error is obviously a bit confusing, but I guess that's how the compiler interprets the code for this particular scenario.

Comment: Wow!!! I can't believe this, but you are right. It is a compile error at somewhere else but showing errors in Tuple's line.

Comment: I lost half an hour trying to understand this problem and the missing ";" was 4 lines after the one with the tuple and completely unrelated.